# Is it possible to restrict method / resource from being published in application.wadl?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

In my app, there are certain api urls that are published in application.wadl. But now I want to create certain internal api methods / resource that won't get published in application.wadl. Is it possible?

I'm using jersey-module-version : 1.8